# How are limits in mysql on size of columns etc calculated

Tags: mysql, size

From the mysql docs,

[1 - on joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/joins-limits.html),

> The maximum number of tables that can be referenced in a single join is `61`. This also applies to the number of tables that can be referenced in the definition of a view.

[2 - row size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-count-limit.html)

> Every table (regardless of storage engine) has a maximum row size of 65,535 bytes

[3 - on number of columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-count-limit.html)

> There is a hard limit of 4096 columns per table
>
> InnoDB permits up to 1000 columns.]

Is there an explanation of how these numbers have been calculated, or are these all constants assumed during system design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The 61 is probably arbitrary.  If you have a 61-way JOIN, you have an awful schema.
2. The row size limit is not quite right.  What page is that on?  It is ignoring that MEDIUM/LONGTEXT/BLOB fields are not included in that limit.  (But, for that matter, I don't know where 64K-1 applies.)  In InnoDB, there is an "about 8K" limit excluding TEXT, etc that can be pushed to off-block storage.
3. The InnoDB limit was raised to 1017 recently.  The 4096 limit smells like a 12-bit fields in the Handler (Engine-agnostic) code.

I like limits, too.  [Here are some more](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits).

Comment: That website is fantastic, and thanks for your answer :)

Comment: I am going through other posts on your site, and they are really informative. I've been looking for a similar resource for a few days now to get a better understanding of mysql internals. I will offer a bounty for your answer once the link is available to me. Thanks again :)

Comment: Thanks.  My posts were derived from interacting with hundreds of DBAs, engineers, architects, plus from thousands of forum questions.  I see a recurring question/problem, I think about it, study it, experiment, then I post a focused solution.  The charset blog needs a major overhaul; I'm not happy with it.  I started worrying about that topic a decade ago.  I'll bet your handle gets Mojibaked into `mu ç„¡`.